# PHP to read & parse big sized file?

Tags: php, file, memory, file-get-contents, fread

I am about to read a text file sized 200Mb and then edit something inside and then to save it back. But i'm having errors. So:

- Which exact settings should be modified in php?

Also what file reading method is the best for opening & parsing the Big Sized files? I mean:

- fread ?
- file_get_contents ?

Comment: What are the errors you are getting with it? They will go a long way to solving your problem.

Comment: Do you really need the entire file in memory in order to parse it? If not, use `fread()` to read one or few lines at a time and `fwrite()` to write to another (modified) file.

Comment: Have you tried reading the file in chunks with [`fgets`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) let's say?

Comment: fread will work if you use it wisely, you can make a loop and read only small portions of it until you reach the end of the file (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) . Upon saving you can do it using fwrite.

Comment: What is your script supposed to do with the text file, give some more details.

Comment: Why this question is closed??? Is it a dump questionnnn??? I'm tired of this site >.<

Answer (score 6):

I had to do something similar, reading 1GB file. I wanted to stay whithin PHP, so finally I used [fread](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) to read parts of the file, bit by bit:

```
while (!feof($source_file)) {
    $buffer = fread($source_file, 1024);  // use a buffer of 1024 bytes
    $buffer = str_replace($old,$new,$buffer);
    fwrite($target_file, $buffer);
}
```

This way only a small part of the file is kept in memory at any given time. I've checked the efficiency 
and it's good, about half minute for the whole file.

A small note- if the replaced string is in at the end of the buffer it might not be replaced. to make sure you've change all of the occurrences run the script again with a small offset:

```
$buffer = fread($source_file, 512);
fwrite($target_file, $buffer);  
while (!feof($source_file)) {
    $buffer = fread($source_file, 1024);  // use a buffer of 1024 bytes
    $buffer = str_replace($old,$new,$buffer);
    fwrite($target_file, $buffer);
}
```

Comment: That won't always work if your search string is more than one char :)

Comment: running the algorithm again is not a great option, it's better to know the length of your biggest search string and keep that portion of the previous buffer, append another segment, etc.

Comment: @Jack and again you're right :) I know.... after I wrote this script I ran it on 1GB file, and it took less than 1 minute. So yea, I could have done it as you said, and it would have taken less time, but those 30 sec didn't really matter that much.. if efficiency is important than yea, you're totally right. +1

Comment: @Ja͢ck - this is good to know it is not a good option. but do you have a suggested approach?

Comment: @mikoop it’s explained in the above comment ... if your search string is 10 bytes long, then before the second loop you keep 9 bytes from the end of your buffer and use that as the starting bytes followed by the next X bytes from the file, etc.

Comment: thanks @Ja͢ck we got there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the same as an already existing answer, but with file pointers.

```
$original = fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
$new = fopen("/tmp/outputfile.txt", "w");
if ($original && $new) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        //do modification on $buffer (which is a single line)

        fwrite($new, $buffer);
    }

    fclose($original);
    fclose($new);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to complete a similar task:

```
$file = file_get_contents("/path/to/file");
$lines = explode("\n", $file);

$arr = preg_grep("/search_string/", $lines);

// $arr is now a smaller array of things to match
// do whatever here

// write back to file
file_put_contents("/path/to/file", implode("\n", array_merge($arr, $lines)));
```

Comment: Won't this suffer from the same memory problems that the OP is having?

Answer (score -5):

PHP isn't designed or intended to do this.  You may want to consider using Perl, or changing the text into XML, or putting it into a database.

Doing this the way you're intending means the entire file will be loaded into memory.  If you have multiple users doing the same thing, you'll run out of memory real fast.

For XML parsing, look here [XMLReader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily make sense that you can just convert any old text file to XML, for one thing. We don't know the source of the text files or what they contain, so putting them in a database is not necessarily an option either if it must be done on the fly with a PHP script (if we're able to read the file to do so, the problem is already solved).

Comment: @WesleyMurch It doesn't make sense that you would process such a large file with PHP either.  The OP never specified that it HAD to be a text file.  I was simply pointing out better options.  I don't understand why that would get downvoted.  If there was more information to begin with, I may not have suggested it.  But everything I posted in my answer is true.